# Weird black lines when rendering in my Java Game Engine

Tags: java, rendering

I have an issue regarding weird horizontal and vertical lines that occur in my game engine. The lines is in the background color. It occurs when I draw a lot of tiles in this way:

```
for (int y = iy; y < camera.getY() + renderer.getpHeight(); y+= image2.getHeight()) {
    for (int x = ix; x < camera.getX() + renderer.getpWidth(); x+=image2.getWidth()) {
        renderer.drawImage(x, y , image2);
    }
}
```

The lines appear when I move the "camera" around.

The way I am rendering the tiles is not a good way to do it, which I have understood due to the drop in FPS. I am currently thinking on a way to make it more optimized. I don't think that the bad optimization is the reason for the black lines however. Here is a GIF of the phenomenon:

[image: GIF]

Comment: What are the types of all these variables and method return parameters? Any float's or double's in there?

Comment: @Philipp When drawing an image I only use integers. So in this case x and y need to be integers otherwise it wont work. Some might have been cast to integer from float values however. Does it affect the images? Because the same thing happens when drawing a big image and then moving the camera. Its weird.

Comment: What I suspect is that conversions between floats and integers cause rounding errors which then lead to a gap appearing between tiles. But that's just a guess. Can you provide more information about where those gaps appear? Are they always at specific coordinates? Or does it vary?

Comment: I honestly don’t know if it varies or not. I’ll take a look and get back to you. I’ll see if I can add some more information as well :)

Comment: Yep that solved the issue, I had a speed variable in the type float that made the pixels appear weird! Thanks for the help!

Comment: When you were able to solve your problem on your own, please post an own answer which explains what lead to the problem and how you solved it. Then accept your own answer so this question no longer appears as unanswered.

Comment: I'll do that, it says I have to wait until tomorrow however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The black lines occured due to me not rounding float values properly. In my engine I can only set a pixel on **x** and **y** values that are **integers**. In my case I had a float variable called speed that was added onto the cameras x and y position (which also is of type float).

I solved the issue by rounding the speed and camera variables. This made the black lines / gaps disappear.